# Why is magento 1.9 presenting same products whatever the category when all cache are activated?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cache

On our site http://printplus.frezalsublimation.fr/ when all caches are activated, when you click  on the category, Magento remembers the page, and subsequent clicks to other categories present the same products?

I need to activate the cache because otherwise the site is slow to display the products. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is caching active now? I am seeing different products in different categories

Comment: Sorry I had to take some action rapidly for the production, I activated all the different caches EXCEPT "block HTML Output" which seems to solve the problem, I don't know why.